# .NET 5, ASP.NET Blazor return DataAnnotation errors instead of JSON Parser Errors

Tags: asp.net-web-api, blazor, data-annotations, .net-5, jsonparser

Is there a way to get the DataAnnotation Errors rather than the JSON Parser Errors?

I have a model. Relevant fields, for example, are:

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"^(?i)(true|false)$", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be either 'true' or 'false'")]

public bool IsStudent { get; set; }
        
[Required]
[StringLength(50)]
[DataType(DataType.Text)]
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Z]+[a-zA-Z\-]*$", ErrorMessage = "FirstName may only contain letters, numbers and dashes.")]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]

public string LastName { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Date Started")]

public DateTime? DateStarted { get; set; }
```

My Controller:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public class PeopleController : Controller
{
    //Removed for brevity
    
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("personupload")]
    [ProducesResponseType(400)]
    [ProducesResponseType(401)]
    [ProducesResponseType(401)]
    public IActionResult CreatePersonBatch([FromBody] IEnumerable<PersonImport> people)
    {
        //I understand this is not necessary
        //Trying to see if it makes a difference. It does not.
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        // Goes on to create data table
    }
}
```

When I send the following with Postman,

```json
[
  {
    "LocationId": 0,
    "RankId": 0,
    "IsStudent": a,
    "IsProspect": true,
    "IsVendor": true,
    "IsAppUser": true,
    "FirstName": "string",
    "LastName": "<Student>",
    "BirthDate": "2021-03-14",
    "Gender": "string",
    "UniformTopSize": "string",
    "UniformBottomSize": "string",
    "BeltSize": "string",
    "DateStarted": "now",
    "DateLastAttended": "2021-03-14",
    "IsHoh": true
  }
]
```

I get the following response:

```json
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-f2bde8fdc701de458f1d86297b7e4813-bdd66281fab85348-00",
    "errors": {
        "$[0].IsStudent": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Boolean. Path: $[0].IsStudent | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 20."
        ]
    }
}
```

It appears that the JSON Parser returns an unfriendly error message for the first error it encounters. I would like to return a list of friendly(ier) errors to API users as the DataAnnotation errors does. I can't seem to find out how to pre-empt the JSON Parser.